# Java TreeMap not sorted according to passed comparator

Tags: java, android, comparator, treemap

I have implemented a TreeMap that contains blueprints (to simplify it).

```
private TreeMap<BuildingFloorKey, Blueprint> blueprints = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> {
        int value = o1.compareTo(o2);
        return value;
});
```

To use building (in my case called complex) and floor as a tuple key, I wrote the following class:

```
public static class BuildingFloorKey {
    private Complex mComplex;
    private int mFloor;

    public BuildingFloorKey(Complex complex, int floor){
        mComplex = complex;
        mFloor = floor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof BuildingFloorKey)) return false;
        BuildingFloorKey that = (BuildingFloorKey) other;
        return mFloor == that.mFloor && mComplex.equals(that.mComplex);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[]{mComplex, mFloor});
    }

    public int compareTo(BuildingFloorKey otherKey){
        if(this.equals(otherKey)) return 0;

        //same complex -> compare floors
        else if (this.getComplex().equals(otherKey.getComplex())){
            return otherKey.getFloorInt() - this.getFloorInt();
        }
        //different complexes (incl. some modification for special cases)
        else return -(Math.abs(otherKey.mFloor + 2) + 100);
    }
}
```

I am working on an Android App and I want to click through the blueprints via buttons. For that I make use of the methods TreeMap.lowerKey(otherKey) and TreeMap.higherKey(otherKey). Like so:

```
@Override
    public void onNextPlanClicked() {
           nextFloorPlan = blueprints.higherKey(currentlyDisplayedPlan);
           drawFloorPlan(nextFloorPlan);
        }
```

As an example, I have a usecase where the set of blueprints is

- 04|02
- 03|03
- 04|-1
- 03|00

(format: complex|floor). Unfortunately, it is not sorted properly in the TreeMap (as you can see - the list above is sorted like the entries of the TreeMap in the debugger).

I read something about TreeMap Sorting using case-sensitive Strings. But I'm actually using integers. So I don't get why sorting and using lowerKey() and higherKey() not working properly. Did I mess up with the comparator? Can someone help please?

Comment: Solved it by changing to a LinkedHashMap (I recognized that the order I am adding entries is the one I want). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issues is a very simple one, your compareTo method should have an override. You need to add implements Comparable to your BuildingFloorKey definition, which will then take your compareTo argument as a comparable that TreeMap can recognize.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good tip for completeness. Solved some crazy button behaviour but, unfortunately, the order of the blueprints is still incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I likely should have commented instead of answering. Looking at your compareTo method the third equation is off. It essentially says return negative number. Thats all it says, for compareTo we only care about +/-/0. So it'll make a mess of sorting because if they're different complexes whichever one is the "other" complex will always register as higher.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Indeed I had this thought too and then forgot about it. So compareTo just returns results saying "is smaller", "is larger" and "is equal", am I right now?

Comment: This corrected the behaviour! Although I recognized some details and use cases in my project which made me change everything ;) But thanks a lot!